# Sub query result is 0

Tags: apex, query, subquery

I want to get the Opportunity Ids of the Opportunity records that have associated OpportunityLineItems but no Revenue_Pipeline__c custom object records for a batch class.

I have my sub-query which gives me the results if the records are there, but I can't seem to figure out to filter if there are no results?

```
SELECT Id, Name,
(SELECT Id, Name FROM Revenue_Pipelines__r),
(SELECT Id, Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItems)
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE NPD_Forecast_Category__c = 'Renew'
```

Is there a way to filter in the query to get the Opps that do not have a Revenue Pipeline but do have an Opportunityline. Or do I need to loop through the results and check each one then do the logic after that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual pattern is to use a semi-join:

```
SELECT Id, Name,
(SELECT Id, Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItems)
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE NPD_Forecast_Category__c = 'Renew'
      AND Id NOT IN (SELECT Opportunity_Id__c FROM Revenue_Pipeline__c)
```

This pattern lets the database engine do some of the work for you, so there's no need to loop in Apex and you can return significantly less data.

See the [SOQL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm) for more details - there are some implementation restrictions around using semi- and anti-joins.